# Dynamic added Tabs vs Dynamic added collapsibles

Tags: website-design, scrolling, tabs, collapsible-panels

We are creating dynamic multiple steps form where we have dynamically added form fields by the user and we'd like to group these fields under a common title in either tabs or collapsibles for example:

**In a new tab:**

[image]

**In a new collapsible:**
[image]

Both look nice but when you have a large amount of items you need to do some scrolling (horizontal in tabs and vertical in collapsible).

So the Question is Which form will be more intuitive and correct

Answer (score 3):

Having so many tabs that the user must scroll horizontally is never a good idea. It's very fiddly and breaks the tab analogy. I would only use tabs if the number of tabs was predictable and limited.

If your user can create a large number or theoretically infinite number of items, I think a vertical list (scrolling if necessary) would be more appropriate.